# loopback on tcp port from localhost to localhost

Tags: osx-lion, netstat, loopback, rootkit

I've seen running `netstat` that there are two strange tcp connection opened:

```
tcp4       0      0  localhost.49153    localhost.1023 ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  localhost.1023     localhost.49153 ESTABLISHED
```

I wonder if it is normal. Can someone help me? thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's just normal loopback used by OS X. Checkout a Apples port usage [publication](http://support.apple.com/kb/ts1629)

```
 port          service      description
-------------+------------+------------------
 600-1023    | ipcserver  | Mac OS X RPC-based services
 49152-65535 | Xsans      | Xsan Filesystem Access
 49152-65535 | misc       | Back to My Mac
```